# SAP Webi Frequency Table

Tags: hana, business-objects, webi

I am quite new to using Business Objects (SAP HANA) Web Intelligence (Webi). As you can tell, I don't even know what to call this environment I am working in.

I have a table with multiple columns. I am interested in one particular column called **[Red_Green]**. This column contains *"GRAY"*, *"RED"*, *"GREEN"*, *"YELLOW"* and *""* (blanks).

I am trying to create a table of counts for each occurrence of the values. For example:

```
Red_Green
RED
RED
GREEN

GREEN
GRAY

YELLOW
```

I want to get a table that shows:

```
RED GREEN YELLOW GRAY BLANK

2     2     1     1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a crosstab. Search for "Working with Tables and Crosstabs" at the following link for some guidance in working with crosstabs.

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Tutorials+-+SAP+Web+Intelligence

You could also get your desired result with a horizontal table. In either case just remove the column or row headers you don't want.

You will need to a create a variable to count the instances of each value in the **Red_Green** column like this...

```
=Count([Red_Green]; All)
```

You need to specify "All" so that it counts each instance of the value and not just unique values.

Also, if you truly want to display "BLANK" as the header for the count of blank or NULL values you will need to create variable as shown below and count that instead.

```
=If([Red_Green] = "" Or IsNull([Red_Green]);  "BLANK"; [Red_Green])
```

Then you count variable formula would look like this...

```
=Count([Red_Green With Blanks]; All)
```

To put them in the order you have you can create a custom sort order.

[image]

Hope this gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: I was able to get this done in R using: "my_data %>% group_by(Coreid) %>% mutate(count = n())"

Still no luck making it work with BO.

Comment: Saw this was still not working for you. I think it might because you need to check for NULL rather than a blank (""). I'll update my answer.